# How do i disable messenger on the iMac but not my MacBook/iPhone

Tags: macos, messages

I have an iPhone and MacBook that are my own and an iMac that I share with my fiancé. I have it set up currently so that my text messages come to my phone and both computers.

As this can be annoying when she is using the home computer and I am not (getting my random texts), how do I disable Messages on the iMac but not my MacBook/iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the Messages app, all you need to do is sign out of it on the iMac.

To do this:

1. Launch the Messages app on the iMac
2. Go to Messages menu > Preferences
3. Select the Accounts icon
4. Click on your account (in the left-hand column)
5. Click on the Sign Out button (on the right-hand side)

When you exit the Messages app it will no longer receive your messages.